# Javascript regex question

Tags: javascript, regex

What's the intent of () inside the regex? Thanks.

```
pattern.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g,
        function(pattern, index) { 
            return args[index].toString(); 
        });
```

PS: args is something like ["3", "dl1", "42"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used to manage grouping.

The purpose of grouping is to make backreferences on searches & replaces. Using regex you can make that `Jhon Doe` becomes `Doe, Jhon`.

To achieve that, you would use a Regex `(\w*) (\w*)` with two grups, and replace it for `$2, $1`

Usually, the first group (0) references the whole match of the regex, being the other groups numbered according to the order where they are in your expression.

Comment: +1: But I would add that not all groups are capturing groups. Some just affect the operation of *,+,?,| etc

Comment: Hi can u make a example for your answer? Thanks.

Comment: I use a regex (Java format, it is quite similar to Javascript) to parse jdbc oracle connection chain:
`jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=test)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID = sidbbdd))`
I need it to fin the host, so I would write
`.*@.*HOST=(\w*)\).*`
This regex will ignore pretty much everything until it finds `HOST=` then, it will find everything until it finds `)` and ignore the rest of the chain.
To reference the part of my host I would use $1, which would return `test`.

Comment: Should I need further matchings of subsets of the regex, I would use more groups, for instance

`(.*@.*)HOST=(\w*)\)(.*)`

would return:

$0 --> `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=test)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID = sidbbdd))`

$1 --> `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(`

$2 --> `test`

$3 --> `(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID = sidbbdd))`

Answer (score 2):

It creates a group.

What is `args`?

Comment: something like ["3", "dl1", "42"]

Comment: Hi, what's the purpose to create groups here?